# Get type from enum

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, enums

I'm working on a struct:

```
struct memory {
    enum data_type {
        INT, DOUBLE, SHORT
    };
    data_type dtype;

    void* get_data_handle() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

With this struct, I can describe some data in memory including its type (with the enum `dtype`) and data pointer. I can't modify the design of this struct.

Now I want to handle the data, so I can first use the function `get_data_handle` to get a `void` pointer, and then convert the pointer to the corresponding type. For example, if I have an object `memory m;`, and I know in advance that `m.dtype = memory::data_type::DOUBLE`, so I can safely using `reinterpret_cast<double*>(m.get_data_handle()>` to get the data pointer with the right type.

Here is the question, is there any elegant method which can do this when I don't know the `dtype` in advance? Just like something like:

```
auto data_ptr = reinterperet_cast<get_type(m.dtype)>(m.get_data_handle());
```

Comment: No. C++ does not work this way. `reinterpret_cast`, et all, gets parsed and compiled at compile time, not run time. Template parameters must therefore be known at compile time.

Comment: Yes, of course we cannot do it exactly like the way I said. I mean some thing like that, such as type traits?

Comment: You should have a switch block with each case handling particular `data_type` value, casting pointer accordingly and utilizing it.

Comment: You can look at `variant` and its visitor.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. If the caller plans to call `foo(double)` given a `memory`, he already knows he's got to check first for a `memory::data_type::DOUBLE`. In general, the caller has some idea what to do with the data, and therefore what types to expect. A bit of code that just _holds_ a `memory` value might not care, but then you don't have the problem of extracting a value either.